# An example of a Sylow permutable subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I need an example of a finite group $G$ with a Sylow permutable subgroup $H$, such that the order of $H^G/Core_G(H)$ is  divisible by at least two distinct primes. Could you please help me?

---

1. $H^G=\langle g^{-1}Hg | g\in G\rangle$
2. We know that $H^G/Core_G(H)$ is nilpotent
3. $H$ is a Sylow permutable of $G$ means that for all $Q \in Syl(G)$, $HQ=QH$

Comment: What is Sylow permutable subgroup ? Is $Q$ allowed to be for difftent prime ?

Comment: Yes, @mesel 

Definition. Let $X$ be a family of subgroups of a group $G
$. A subgroup $H$ of
a group $G$ is called $X$-permutable if $H$ permutes with all subgroups $A \in X$. Here $X=Syl(G)$

Comment: Can you give some details and intuition about this question?

Comment: As i mentioned, we know that $H^G/Core_G(H)$ is nilpotent in this situation, but all the examples  I have found are indeed $p$-groups. @mesel

Comment: I'm largely uneducated about this. Can't immediately think of a Sylow permutable (of a non-abelian group $G$) other than $H=A_3\le S_3=G$. In that case $H^G/Core(H)$ is easily seen to be $\simeq C_2$. Can you give more examples? Just for us to get a feel of what Sylow permutable really looks like? Edit: After reading Derek Holt's example I reallize that $H^G/Core(H)$ is trivial. Don't know what I was thinking :-(

Answer (score 2):

For a prime $p$, let $G_p$ be any $p$-group having a non-normal subgroup $H_p$. Then $H_p^{G_p}/{\rm Core}_{G_p}(H_p)$ is a nontrivial $p$-group.

Now let $G$ be a direct product of some of these groups $G_p$ for different primes $p$, and let $H$ be the direct product of the subgroups $H_p$.

Then all Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal, so all of its subgroups are Sylow permutable. In particular, $H$ is Sylow permutable, and $H^G/{\rm Core}_G(H)$ is the direct product of the nontrivial groups  $H_p^{G_p}/{\rm Core}_{G_p}(H_p)$.